# Definition of Standard Brownian Filtration

Tags: brownian-motion

I am trying to learn about stochastic calculus for my research, so self study, and I came across the notion of a Standard Brownian Filtration. I cannot find a good definition of what the Standard Brownian Filtration is, and I was wondering if anyone had a good definition or a link to one. I do not think they define it in the book I am reading and I cannot find a definition online easily.

Comment: Maybe the natural filtration of a standard brownian motion.

Comment: By this you mean the filtration that a Brownian Motion is over?

Comment: I mean the filtration defined by $\mathcal{F}_t=\sigma(W_s\colon s\leq t)$

Comment: What is the definition of that?

Comment: Never mind, I understand now. Thank you

Comment: $\mathcal{F}_t$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the family of random variables $(W_s)_{s\leq t}$, where $W$ is your brownian motion.